# How to rewrite / restructure JSON from external URL?

Tags: php, json

This is a question that has been around for a long time when I think of asking here at StackOverflow. I've searched all over the internet for a solution, but I was not successful. I didn't find any subject about.

> The question is: **is it possible to rewrite, say (restructure) an existing external JSON file?**

Imagine that you want to eliminate some objects that you don't use, or translate objects from some API, or just make it cleaner.

**Example JSON file:**

```
{
  "content" : [ {
    "userId" : 3370,
    "year" : 2015,
    "unity" : {
      "organ" : {
        "entity" : {
          "entityId" : 2102309,
          "name" : "Jack Sparrow"
        },
    "type" : null,
    "lic" : [ ]
  }],
  "numberOfElements" : 1,
  "totalPages" : 0,
  "totalElements" : 1,
  "firstPage" : true,
  "lastPage" : false,
  "size" : 0,
  "number" : 0
}
```

**Example - Output - JSON file - Restructured: (result)**

```
[
  {
    "userId": 3370,
    "year": 2015,
    "entityId": "2102309",
    "name": "Jack Sparrow"
  }
]
```

> What is the most efficient way to do this restructuring via **PHP**?

I was trying something like this in PHP:

```
<?php
$json_strdoc = file_get_contents("https://example.com/arquivojson"); //Get the file

    $objdoc = json_decode($json_strdoc); //Decoding JSON

   echo "["; //Beginning
        foreach ($objdoc as $itemdoc){  //Printing elements individually

            echo "

  {
    "usuarioId": $itemdoc->content->userId,
    "ano": $itemdoc->content->year,
    "entidadeId": $itemdoc->content->unity->organ->entity->entityId,
    "nome": $itemdoc->content->unity->organ->entity->name
  },
"
   echo "]"; //End

?>
```

I am not an expert in PHP, so I am exemplifying with a code that I know is wrong, but that is more understood. I haven't found the correct way to print the new JSON file.

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by echoing strings. Create new arrays containing what you want, and then call `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Barmar Could you give an example as an answer?

Comment: Asking for a library is off-topic, but [look here](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/10208-PHP-Query-JSON-data-to-find-and-extract-information.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you need to create an associative array of the values you want and push that into an overall result array. At the end of your loop, output the `json_encode` result of that array:

```
$json_strdoc = file_get_contents("https://example.com/arquivojson"); //Get the file

$objdoc = json_decode($json_strdoc); //Decoding JSON
$output = array();
foreach ($objdoc->content as $content) {
    $item = array(
        "usuarioId" => $content->licitacaoId,
        "ano" => $content->anoProcesso,
        "entidadeId" => $content->unidade->orgao->ente->enteId,
        "nome" => $content->unidade->orgao->ente->nome
    );
    $output[] = $item;
} 
echo json_encode($output);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/K3p12)

Comment: The JSON in your question is invalid. Could you please update with actual JSON?

Comment: The JSON file to be used is this: http://app.tce.ma.gov.br:8889/licitacoes?enteId=2102309 - I put a smaller example for a better understanding.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes I've updated my answer based on the JSON from that URL. I guessed what field you want for `usarioId` and `ano`, you can change them if you need to. I also added a demo with a small part of the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array containing what you want and call `json_encode()`.

Also, the array is in `$objdoc->content`, not `$objdoc`. You should loop over that, not use `$itemdoc->content` inside the loop.

```
<?php
$json_strdoc = file_get_contents("https://example.com/arquivojson"); //Get the file
$objdoc = json_decode($json_strdoc); //Decoding JSON
$newdoc = array_map(function($itemdoc) {
    return ["usuarioId" => $itemdoc->userId,
            "ano" => $itemdoc->year,
            "entidadeId" => $itemdoc->unity->organ->entity->entityId,
            "nome" => $itemdoc->unity->organ->entity->name];
}, $objdoc->content);
echo json_encode($newdoc);
```

Comment: Could you please put the whole code snippet for a better understanding? I'm using a translator.

Comment: I added the first two lines, but they're the same as your code.

Comment: Something went wrong. Syntax error on line 10. `echo json_encode($newdoc);`

Comment: Missing semicolon at the end of the previous line.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/VLsgVsZ0/maluco.png - Look how I edited it. - It is returning null.

Comment: The JSON is invalid. The line before `numberOFElements` should be `}}],`

Comment: The JSON file to be used is this: app.tce.ma.gov.br:8889/licitacoes?enteId=2102309 - I put a smaller example for a better understanding. I will edit the question.

Comment: I think my code should work with the real JSON, it doesn't have that problem. But you also translated all the property names, so I can't easily test it.

Comment: I'm going to do some tests here. I believe it will work.